# Finding users that have made a reservation within 1 month of signing up

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how a query that will allow me to compare the number of users that have signed up in a given week to the number of users that have signed up and made a restaurant reservation within that same week. This is to help me understand activation rates of users on our app.

So far I have the following code which gives me the number of users that have signed up within a given week as well as the total number of reservations placed in that week. But what I am now trying to find is the number of users that have placed a reservation within their first week of signing up. Any help with this would be great.

```
SELECT
    (DATE_TRUNC('week', (users.created_at::timestamptz))) AS week,
    COUNT(users.created_at) AS new_users,
    COUNT(reservations.covers) AS reservations_placed,
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN reservations ON users.id = reservations.user_id
    LEFT JOIN restaurants ON reservations.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
    LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.id = restaurants.region_id
WHERE reservations.denied_at IS NULL
    AND reservations.canceled_at IS NULL
    AND reservations.no_show_at IS NULL
    AND reservations.origin != 'in_house'
    AND reservations.origin != 'web'
GROUP BY
    week
ORDER BY
    week
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.